# Configurar XCODE

Tags: ios, xcode

Estoy desarrollando aplicaciones hibridas con Ionic 3, siempre que he desarrollado para iOS lo he hecho con cuentas de desarrollador ya sea de personas o de empresas, pero resulta que ahora estoy haciendo un desarrollo personal y no cuento con una cuenta. Es posible configurar XCODE para ejecutar en dispositivos sin tener una cuenta?

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres exactamente?¿A poder desarrollar sin tener una cuenta propia de desarrollador? ¿O a publicar de algún modo?

Comment: No, disculpa si me exprese mal, pero es para poder ejecutar en un dispositivo. No puedo ya que me piden los certificados y los profiles

Comment: Creo que te tienes que hacer una cuenta de desarrollador y asociarla a XCode, aunque no tienes por qué pagar la cuota hasta que no estés listo para publicar la app. Al menos así es como yo lo hice (y como tendré que volver s hacerlo porque dejé de pagar la cuota anual)

Comment: Si eso habia leido, pero no se donde se hace eso de anexar la cuenta, porque me autentique con mi apple id pero no funciono!!!

Comment: Deja y lo miro. Llevo casi dos años sin publicar para iOS 

Comment: Gracias @AlvaroMontoro

Comment: Aun no encuentro :( parece que tendre que pagar xD